# SVG Eyes Following Cursor but with a fixed highlight

Tags: javascript, animation, svg

I followed @[chrwahl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/322084/chrwahl) answer to a question here:

[Make eyes follow cursor in this SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74828232/make-eyes-follow-cursor-in-this-svg?newreg=7700c3c2a9b848a78c3fa4f83d7779ca)

But I would like to bring a little life to the eyes and have a highlight in the pupil. Problem is, if I add a gradient to the pupil, the highlight rotates around with the pupil instead of always staying in the upper right side of the pupil.

I tried calculating the angle of the lines guiding the pupil, subtracting it from 360 and rotating the circle element by that amount to try and counter the rotation of the pupil, but the rotation moves the circle element out of the viewbox for the marker. I tried setting the transform origin, but that didn't appear to work either.

```js
let l1 = document.querySelector("#l1");
let l2 = document.querySelector("#l2");
let svg1 = document.querySelector("#svg1");

const toSVGPoint = (svg, x, y) => {
    let p = new DOMPoint(x, y);
    return p.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
};

document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
    let p = toSVGPoint(svg1, e.clientX, e.clientY);
    l1.setAttribute('x2', p.x);
    l1.setAttribute('y2', p.y);
    l2.setAttribute('x2', p.x);
    l2.setAttribute('y2', p.y);

    //Line 1 Points
    const l1x1 = parseFloat(l1.getAttribute('x1'));
    const l1y1 = parseFloat(l1.getAttribute('y1'));
    const l1x2 = parseFloat(l1.getAttribute('x2'));
    const l1y2 = parseFloat(l1.getAttribute('y2'));
    //Line 2 Points
    const l2x1 = parseFloat(l2.getAttribute('x1'));
    const l2y1 = parseFloat(l2.getAttribute('y1'));
    const l2x2 = parseFloat(l2.getAttribute('x2'));
    const l2y2 = parseFloat(l2.getAttribute('y2'));

    // Calculate the angle in radians
    const l1AngleRad = Math.atan2(l1y2 - l1y1, l1x2 - l1x1);
    const l2AngleRad = Math.atan2(l2y2 - l2y1, l2x2 - l2x1);

    // Convert the angle to degrees
    const l1AngleDeg = l1AngleRad * (180 / Math.PI);
    const l2AngleDeg = l2AngleRad * (180 / Math.PI);

    // Get the object element
    const object = document.querySelector('.pupils');
    
    // Function to rotate the object
    function rotateObject(degrees) {
      object.style.transform = `rotate(${degrees - 180}deg)`;
    }
    
    // Rotate the object by 45 degrees
    rotateObject(l1AngleDeg);

});
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 50">
    <circle cx="75" cy="25" r="20" fill="none" stroke="black" />
    <circle cx="125" cy="25" r="20" fill="none" stroke="black" />
    <line marker-start="url(#pupil)" id="l1" x1="75" y1="25" stroke="none" />
    <line marker-start="url(#pupil)" id="l2" x1="125" y1="25" stroke="none" />
    <defs>
        <radialGradient id="lightFlare" cx="0.5" cy="0.5" r="0.5" fx="0.25" fy="0.3">
            <stop offset="0" stop-color="#fff" />
            <stop offset=".45" stop-color="#030507" />
        </radialGradient>
        <marker id="pupil" viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="16" refY="5" markerWidth="10" markerHeight="10" orient="auto-start-reverse">
            <circle class="pupils" fill="url(#lightFlare)" stroke="green" r="4" cy="5" cx="5" />
        </marker>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Does anyone have any ideas how I can get the highlight to counter the rotation of the pupils and always be in the upper right side of the pupil?

Comment: Maybe you can take inspiration from [this](https://codepen.io/ccprog/pen/bGLOZoE) solution to a comparable problem. In short, the radial gradient is applied as partial transparency to a non-rotated circle drawn **on top** of the rotating ball.

Comment: Instead of  `object.style.transform` try using object.setAttribute("transform",`rotate(${degrees - 180} 5 5)`) where 5 5 is the center of the circle. A different approach would be keeping your javascript and changing the marker to `<marker id="pupil" viewBox="-5 -5 10 10" refX="11" refY="0" ...` and delete the cx and cy attributes of the circle inside

Comment: You might also revisit my [alternative approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74828232/make-eyes-follow-cursor-in-this-svg#74851155). Since it doesn't depend on any rotations it will also work (appended a new example) and it doesn't require auxiliary line elements.

Answer (score 0):

The technique using [`<marker>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/marker) in [my original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74843398/322084) was simple, but too limited in relation to your question. With that said, the answer to your question is almost as simple.

So, here are two circles (`#c1` and `#c2`) with the gradient you created. They are not "attached" to anything. The lines (`#l1` and `#l2`) have their `x2` and `y2` attributes updated on mouse move. Then asking for the [getPointAtLength()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGeometryElement/getPointAtLength) at a certain length (here 11) on the lines, regardless of the length of the lines, we will always get a point with the same distance to the start of the lines aka. the center of the eyes. Now, we can just position the circles/pupils at that point.

This is an even better solution than the original. Thank you for asking!

```js
let svg1 = document.querySelector("#svg1");
let l1 = document.querySelector("#l1");
let l2 = document.querySelector("#l2");
let c1 = document.querySelector("#c1");
let c2 = document.querySelector("#c2");

const toSVGPoint = (svg, x, y) => {
  let p = new DOMPoint(x, y);
  return p.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
};

document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  let p = toSVGPoint(svg1, e.clientX, e.clientY);
  l1.setAttribute('x2', p.x);
  l1.setAttribute('y2', p.y);
  l2.setAttribute('x2', p.x);
  l2.setAttribute('y2', p.y);
  let p1 = l1.getPointAtLength(11);
  c1.setAttribute('cx', p1.x);
  c1.setAttribute('cy', p1.y);
  let p2 = l2.getPointAtLength(11);
  c2.setAttribute('cx', p2.x);
  c2.setAttribute('cy', p2.y);
});
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 50">
  <circle cx="75" cy="25" r="20" fill="none" stroke="blue" />
  <circle cx="125" cy="25" r="20" fill="none" stroke="blue" />
  <line id="l1" x1="75" y1="25" x2="0" y2="25" stroke="red" />
  <line id="l2" x1="125" y1="25" x2="0" y2="25" stroke="red" />
  <circle id="c1" cx="64" cy="25" r="5" fill="url(#lightFlare)" />
  <circle id="c2" cx="114" cy="25" r="5" fill="url(#lightFlare)" />
  <defs>
    <radialGradient id="lightFlare" cx="0.5" cy="0.5" r="0.5" fx="0.25" fy="0.3">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#fff" />
      <stop offset=".45" stop-color="#030507" />
    </radialGradient>
  </defs>
</svg>
```